# Joins on Hive tables Mapped to HBase

Tags: hbase, hive

We have created tables in HBase and those tables are mapped to Hive using HBase Storage Handler. If the tables are having huge records say 100Millions, and if we need to join the two tables based on some column and if those columns are not row key id column, how will be the performance, is there any way that we can increase the performance in table joins for Hive tables mapped to HBase.

Regards,
GHK.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which underlying storage are you using for Hive JOIN performance. So HBase rowkey doesn't helps you out with Hive.

One trick which you can use is mapjoin which works very well if you are joining small table with huge one.

You can read more about Hive JOIN performance on this link https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/join-optimization-in-apache-hive/470667928919

Comment: I got it, but in Hive we have partitions which well help us limit the number of records for join operation, if we have a hive mapping table of HBase, then is there a way we achieve faster response in table joins

Comment: I think that's not currently possible with HBase storage handler. Check out this JIRA which is about that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1223